How do I use one colormap to filter data on another colormap?
I have two colormaps which are both created using arrays of (n,n) size (n being an even integer).
The first represents the intensity of a light beam on a surface.
Intensity across the surface
The other represents the polarization of the beam across the same surface, at the same time.
Polarization of the beam across the surface in °
I would like to only show values of the second colormap where there is a certain amount of intensity.
It would be even better if the gradient of the first colormap could be applied over the second colormap.

Can you use alpha for the intensity?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

You can create a mask array of 0 and 1, with the same dimensions and size as the image and set the values of this mask to 1 where the intensity is above your threshold, then multiply the polarisation by this mask.
Let's say you have the two arrays intensity and polarisation. The mask array will be 0 except where intensity is above the threshold.
import numpy as np

intensity = np.ones((50,50)) * np.random.rand(50,50)
polarisation = np.ones((50,50))
threshold = 0.5

mask = np.zeros(np.shape(intensity))

mask[np.where(intensity>threshold)] = 1

filtered_polarisation = polarisation * mask


Great ! If you can accept the answer (tick mark to the left of the text) it will clarify it for other users.

Ah ok, it should be done now.
